# iptables --dport option not working

Tags: iptables, firewall

I am trying to set a few iptables rules on my Raspberry Pi running Raspbian stretch, but I have difficulties to restrict rules to destination ports.

The following rule is accepted:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -j DROP
```

However, when I try to specify the destination port for the rule with `--dport` (which should work according to all the documentation I have found, see e.g. [this SE answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/561248/768675)), it throws me an error and does not append the rule:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 -j DROP
iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
```

**UPDATE:**

The problem is not present on a fresh install of Raspbian Stretch. I am still at a loss, why it is not working with my other SD-card. Are there any applications that inhibit mechanisms of iptables that could cause those errors?

Comment: It looks perfectly acceptable. Please try retyping the line (don't copy and paste) in case there's an invisible character (eg cursor movement) embedded in there somewhere.

Comment: @roaima thanks for the suggestion. I just tried typing the full line anew. Unfortunately with the same result.

Comment: Have your tried with `sudo -- iptables ...` just in case `sudo` does some strange argument processing?

Comment: @Ralph Rönnquist unfortunately the same result. Also `sudo su` did not work.

Comment: Maybe it needs `-m tcp` for `--dport 22` (as well as `-p tcp`)

Comment: @Ralph Rönnquist still the same result. On a Ubuntu machine it worked without any issue. I will try a fresh install of Raspbian next.